# How to dynamic Heart Like in Wordpress?

Tags: comments

I want to dynamic this heart like option in my blog section. The picture is given below.
How can i do This? Thanks for help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this link would be helpful to you

https://hofmannsven.com/2013/laboratory/wordpress-post-like-system/

Comment: how can i do that, this link description isn't clear